# awk command return not found on Ubuntu desktop but work well on Centos

Tags: awk

I create test.sh to read a file with content

```
item1:return1
item2:return2
...
item10:return10
```

test.sh content

```
VAR1=$1
VAR2= `grep "^${VAR1}:" /home/path/file | awk '{print $2;}'`

echo "${VAR2}";
```

run test

```
sh test.sh item1
```

return

```
: not found test.sh: 
: not found test.sh:
```

When I run the same on Centos. return

```
return1
```

What's wrong with awk command ?

Comment: The output looks like the file has CRLF line endings. Did you edit on Windows at some point?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with awk command. Your issue is `test.sh` cannot be found as message shows. CentOS probably sets your path to PATH variable.

Run it as `sh ./test.sh item1` (I assume test.sh is in your current directory)

Edit:
I should have paid better attention to the script, `:` in grep is the issue
This works

```
VAR1=$1
VAR2=`grep "${VAR1}\:" file | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "${VAR2}";
```

However, awk by default does not recognize `:` as a separator, I had to use

```
item1: return1
item2: return2
```

I have no idea how it could work on server or centos without this change

Comment: You are correct test.sh is in my current directory. I tried with "sh ./test.sh item1" result is the same (a bit different)

: not found2: ./test.sh: 
: not found5: ./test.sh:

Comment: Make sure the executable bit is set

Comment: Very strange I can run command very well on Ubuntu server version but can't run on Ubuntu desktop. All the same command.

Comment: Can you show output of `ls -l test.sh`?